# IndexedDB across tabs: Internal error opening backing store for indexedDB.open

Tags: google-chrome, indexeddb

This has similar symptoms to [Internal error opening backing store for indexedDB.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74207049) but I can reproduce this specific issue.

This is happening on Chrome.

We have a PWA that uses `indexedDB` (specifically the [idb](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb) library around it, but I can reproduce the issue without it).

Users regularly open multiple tabs, and often have many windows open at once.

We use `indexedDB` to cache data and local changes - they can close their browser, restart, open it and their tabs are back, including local changes they hadn't saved yet. We also have global users with poor bandwidth and latency as high as 800ms.

They have the option of clearing the cache from inside the app, and we occasionally have to force it on upgrade. This happens on one tab and calls `clear()` on every store in a single transaction. We wipe all the records in each store, but leave the stores intact.

Once this has happened, when the *other* tabs try to open the store they get:

```
error: DOMException: Internal error opening backing store for indexedDB.open.
  code: 0
  message: "Internal error opening backing store for indexedDB.open."
  name: "UnknownError"
```

If they *refresh* the tab this is fixed, but it's a SPA so that only happens occasionally.

We have added checks of `navigator.storage.estimate()` when this happens and it's a long way below quota.

What is causing this?

Any idea how to work around it?